# Where can I find the word link of a word?

Tags: discussion, resources

With eJoy pages, I can see the word's *word link* information like this:

[image: image of word link on the webpage]

This info really helped me memorize vocabulary. Do any dictionary sites provide this information?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about "dictionary sites provid[ing] [certain] information".  It is not about the English Language within the terms of this site, & is therefore 'Off-topic'.

Comment: @TrevorD Resource requests are _totally_ on topic on ELU, just on the meta part of the site. Saying 'off-topic' discourages such questions when they should be _en_ couraged, just if they occur on main, have them migrated to meta.

Comment: Naive231: it is unclear to me what you mean by 'word link'. I you don't mean etymology (which you can find on etymonline), then any good dictionary will tell you how a word is split into pieces.

Comment: @Mitch It's the name of the section the OP boxed in red. It probably means there's a link from  the word to an eJoy site with examples, translations etc. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ejoy-english-word-master/amfojhdiedpdnlijjbhjnhokbnohfdfb?hl=en

Comment: @Mitch OK, Sorry, I wasn't aware of that!

Comment: @Mari-LouA The 'probably' part is what both you and I don't know. One answer guessed but got it wrong. Naive231 should explain what kind of information that link really provides for them. Is it the info _at_ that link, or is it simply the kind of info displayed in the box in the image we see here?

Comment: @Mitch you can see precisely what information is given, the OP added an arrow, it breaks up a word into parts, a root and a suffix, it explains the meaning of the root and the meaning of the suffix. The "probably" I was talking about is where or how that eJoy screenshot appears, it very "probably" appears when you click the link.

Comment: @Mitch 'Mari-LouA' express my intent well. In fact, I even don't know what is the official or formal name about the 'word link' provided by eJoy, so I snapshot screen to express my question.

Answer (score -1):

On dictionary.com, if you go down to the "Word Origin" of a word you can see the different pieces of the word like in your screenshot of eJoy. You have to actually click on the different pieces to see the meanings though, and there is much more information included than on eJoy, so it might be a bit of an information overload. It may help you however.

[image: Origin of word]

[image: Then if you click on 'icon' you can see its definition, like on eJoy]

Comment: I know 'word origin' means, but it isn't what I am looking for.

Comment: Edited the response with pictures. If you go to the word origins you can see the different pieces of the word and their uses/meanings.